# How to compare one value to another in chartJS

Tags: chart.js

I have been working on a broadband management website.I want to show the user how much data he/she  has used.For example if the total data they have in their name is 300GB.If they have used 150GB the remaining is 150GB right?.How to do i visualize this using a doughnut chart,Using ChartJS.

I have some code going but im not sure how to accomplish this please help me out

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var constdata=document.getElementById("constantdata").textContent;
var data=document.getElementById("data").textContent;
console.log(data);
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'doughnut',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: ['red','green'],
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [300,150] //300 being the total data,150 being the data used
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
```

But the above code isnt working out.Assume a doughnut chart,If the used data is 150GB(out of 300).The doughnut 
chart must be like image1(please refer image 1)

But im getting image2(please refer image 2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFTym.png //image 1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG99s.png   //image 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the used data should appear in red, `data` should be defined as follows:

```
data: [used, total - used]
```

Please have a look at your amended code sample below.

```js
const total = 300;
const used = 100;

var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'green'],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [used, total - used]
    }]
  },
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```